# Was Netflix's Castlevania series faithful to the original games?

Tags: castlevania

[According to Nintendo Life](http://www.nintendolife.com/news/2017/02/the_castlevania_netflix_series_will_be_based_on_castlevania_iii_draculas_curse), Netflix's animated Castlevania series is loosely based on *Castlevania III: Dracula's Curse*. I presume adaptations needed to be made, as the original source material left much room for interpretation.

**How faithful was Netflix's Castlevania series to the original games?**

Did the show take liberties with the games? Were the major characters and plot points lifted directly from the originals? Did the show take place alongside Castlevania III, or was it a prequel taking place before the game?

Comment: Haven't seen it yet but did the main character eat food hidden inside walls?

Comment: @Mario Sadly, there was a distinct lack of wall meat.

Comment: Maybe next season.

Answer (score 7):

It's pretty faithful to the series, with some slight differences to make the story more interesting.

They also added a bit of lore in from Symphony of the Night to flesh things out a bit more.

Here's some info on major differences, which contains some spoilers:

> - The story of Lisa and Dracula preludes the main events, along with Alucard's departure from Castlevania. A lot of this was taken from SoTN
>
>  - The Belmonts have been excommunicated from the Church, and are hated by the general population. In the game the Pope requests Trevor's help.
>
>  - Sypha is a Speaker, a nomadic group of oral historians. Some have a penchant for magic. In the game she (not even revealed to be a woman yet) is a witch in the employ of the church to hunt down Dracula)
>
>  - Alucard's story stays fairly the same. He tests Trevor to make sure he's worthy to fight alongside him
>
>  - Grant hasn't been introduced yet, which makes sense since they aren't in Castlevania yet.

Also, as [@Steven](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/163682/was-netflixs-castlevania-series-faithful-to-the-original-games?noredirect=1#comment434671_163696) points out in the comments, there's no music from the games in the show. While the music is OK, it lacks all the iconic tunes fans have come to love. Probably the only major disappointment of the show.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that [the show did not use any music from the original games](https://www.polygon.com/2017/7/10/15948080/netflix-castlevania-music).

Comment: I should have mentioned the music! I actually mentioned this in the review I wrote for my site. While the music is OK, it's not Castlevania music.

Comment: One point maybe also about one specific char (I don't know the original game so not sure if the speakers are part of it): How much "liked" the speakers are by the curch could be mentionable for the one character if the speakers did not exist in the original game (for points of difference)

Comment: As another point of comparison: Screenshots from Castlevania III's opening cutscene showed Dracula's plan to conquer Europe.

Comment: @Thomas - The Speakers aren't in the original game. They're new to the show.

Comment: @Devar-TTY then it could be pointed out as one of the differences (as its only indicated so far) with the addition of how their plight distances that one char from his original curch stance.